# dot net nuget package version override

Tags: c#, .net, nuget-package

I created a class library. The default version was 1.0.0, and then I updated the class and again created the package using this (dotnet pack -p:PackageVersion=1.0.1 -o \packages) command. I realized that I used the wrong directive in the class and the package was created on the wrong path as well. I changed the directives and created again with the same command with same 1.0.1 in a correct folder. I am unable to refer in other classes with using directive. The compiler does not understand that. When I reference 1.0.2 in csproj package reference then the compiler sees that.

Are these versions immutable? Why removing does not work? How can I make it use version 1.0.1? I have spent hours trying different things, and I do not seem to solve this. Help needed please.

Comment: Try deleting bin and obj folders in your project. Although you added new reference it is possible that your project still see old version of the library.

Comment: As you said deleting bin and obj still reference the old one.